# Error: cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse

I get this error at this line:

```
private List<Contractor> contractors = new ArrayList<Contractor>();
```

It says contractor cannot be resolved to a type.  Now what I did here was I had a customer class.  I needed to create a contractor class too which is exactly the same as the customer class.  So I copied everything from the customer class and created a contractor class.  I then added everything in the code below which I thought is the same for the customer class, but something is wrong.

```
public class SwimCalc extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JTabbedPane jtabbedPane; 
    private JPanel Customers;
    private JPanel Contractors; 
    private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

    // this fails
    private List<Contractor> contractors = new ArrayList<Contractor>();

    JTextArea NameTextCustomers, ExistTextCustomers, MessageTextCustomers, 
    NameTextContractors, ExistTextContractors, MessageTextContractors;
    JTextField lengthTextPool, widthTextPool, depthTextPool, volumeTextPool; 

    public SwimCalc() { 
        setTitle("Volume Calculator"); 
        setSize (300, 200); 

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(); 
        topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); 
        getContentPane().add( topPanel ); 

        createCustomers(); 
        createContractors(); 

        jtabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(); 
        jtabbedPane.addTab("Customer", Customers); 
        topPanel.add(jtabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
    }
}
```

Here is the contractor class

```
public JPanel createContractors(){ 
    Contractors = new JPanel(); 
    Contractors.setLayout(null); 

    NameTextContractors = new JTextArea("Select Add Contractor to Add Contractor." +
    "\nSelect Refresh to Refresh This Pane."); 
    NameTextContractors.setLineWrap(true); 
    NameTextContractors.setBounds(10, 10, 390, 150); 
    Contractors.add(NameTextContractors); 

    JButton Exit = new JButton("Exit"); 
    Exit.setBounds(30,170,80,20); 
    Exit.addActionListener(this); 
    Exit.setBackground(Color.white); 
    Contractors.add(Exit); 

    JButton AddContractors = new JButton("Add Contractor"); 
    AddContractors.setBounds(130,170,120,20); 
    AddContractors.setBackground(Color.white); 
    Contractors.add(AddContractors); 

    JButton Refresh = new JButton("Refresh"); 
    Refresh.setBounds(260,170,80,20); 
    Refresh.setBackground(Color.white); 
    Contractors.add(Refresh); 

    ExistTextContractors = new JTextArea("File Contractor.txt does not exist yet." +
    "\nIt will be created when you add Contractor."); 
    ExistTextContractors.setBounds(10, 200, 390, 60); 
    ExistTextContractors.setLineWrap(true); 
    Contractors.add(ExistTextContractors); 
    final JTextArea contArea = new JTextArea(6, 30); 
    final JTextArea ExistTextContractors; 

    ExistTextContractors = new JTextArea(2, 30); 
    ExistTextContractors.setLineWrap(true); 
    ExistTextContractors.setWrapStyleWord(true); 

    AddContractors.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{ 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    new Contractor("Contractor", SwimCalc.this); 

} 
});


Contractors.add(contArea); 
Contractors.add(AddContractors); 

Contractors.add(Refresh); 
Refresh.setMnemonic('R'); 

Refresh.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 

{ 
NameTextContractors.setText ("");
try{
    File contOpen = new File("Contractor.txt"); 
    FileReader contAreaIn = new FileReader(contOpen); 
    contArea.read(contAreaIn, contOpen.getAbsolutePath()); 
    ExistTextContractors.setText("File exists and can be read."); 

} 
catch (IOException e3){ 
    ExistTextContractors.setText("The file could not be read." + e3.getMessage()); 
} 
} 
} 
);
return Contractors; 
} 
class Contractor extends JFrame 
{ 
private String[] states = {"AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE",
        "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", 
        "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", 
        "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", 
        "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"}; 

private JComboBox StateList = new JComboBox(states); 
private JTextField NameText = new JTextField(25); 
private JTextField AddressText = new JTextField(25); 
private JTextField CityText = new JTextField(25); 
private JTextField ZipText = new JTextField(9); 
private JTextField PhoneText = new JTextField(10); 
private JTextField MessageTextContractors = new JTextField(30); 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

private AddContButtonHandler addConHandler = new AddContButtonHandler();
private SwimCalc parent; 

public Contractor(String who, SwimCalc _parent) {
    popUpWindow (who); 
    parent = _parent; 
}

public void popUpWindow(final String who) {
    final JFrame popWindow; 
    popWindow = new JFrame(who); 
    popWindow.setSize(425, 350); 
    popWindow.setLocation(100, 100); 
    popWindow.setVisible(true); 
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

    Container c = new Container(); 

    popWindow.add(c); 

    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

    JPanel one = new JPanel(); 
    JPanel two = new JPanel(); 
    JPanel three = new JPanel(); 
    JPanel four = new JPanel(); 
    JPanel five = new JPanel(); 
    JPanel six = new JPanel(); 

    one.add(new JLabel(who + " Name ")); 
    one.add(NameText); 
    two.add(new JLabel("Address ")); 
    two.add(AddressText); 
    three.add(new JLabel("City ")); 
    three.add(CityText); 
    four.add(new JLabel("State ")); 
    StateList.setSelectedIndex(0); 
    four.add(StateList); 
    four.add(new JLabel("ZIP")); 
    four.add(ZipText); 
    four.add(new JLabel("Phone")); 
    four.add(PhoneText); 
    JButton addwho = new JButton("Add " + who); 
    addwho.setMnemonic('A'); 
    JButton close = new JButton("Exit"); 
    close.setMnemonic('C'); 
    JButton deleteFile = new JButton("Delete File"); 
    deleteFile.setMnemonic('D'); 
    five.add(addwho); 
    five.add(close); 
    five.add(deleteFile); 
    MessageTextContractors.setEditable(false); 
    MessageTextContractors.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER); 

    six.add(MessageTextContractors); 
    c.add(one); 
    c.add(two); 
    c.add(three); 
    c.add(four); 
    c.add(five); 
    c.add(six); 

    deleteFile.setToolTipText("Delete File"); 
    addwho.setToolTipText("Add "+ who); 
    close.setToolTipText("Exit");
    if (who == "Contractor")
        addwho.addActionListener(addConHandler); 
    close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
            NameText.setText(""); 
            AddressText.setText(""); 
            CityText.setText(""); 
            ZipText.setText(""); 
            PhoneText.setText(""); 
            MessageTextContractors.setText(""); 
            popWindow.dispose(); 
        }
    }
); 
deleteFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
MessageTextContractors
.setText(""); 
if (who.equals("Contractor")) { 
File file = new File("Contractor.txt"); 
boolean conFileDeleted = file.delete(); 
if (conFileDeleted) { 
MessageTextContractors 
.setText("Contractor file has been deleted"); 
} else { 
MessageTextContractors 
.setText("There was an error in deleting file");
}
}
}
}
); 
} 
class AddContButtonHandler implements ActionListener { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent addConHandler) { 
        int StateIndex; 
        try { 
            File file = new File("Contractor.txt"); 
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
            boolean success = file.createNewFile();
            if (success) { 
                MessageTextContractors 
                .setText("Contractor.txt file created file added"); 
            } else if (file.canWrite()) { 
                MessageTextContractors 
                .setText("Writing data to Contractor.txt, file added"); 
            } else { 
                MessageTextContractors.setText("Cannot create file: Contractor.txt"); 
            } 
try {
    FileWriter fileW = new FileWriter("Contractor.txt", true); 
    sb.append(NameText.getText()); 
    sb.append("\n"); 
    sb.append(AddressText.getText()); 
    sb.append("\n"); 
    sb.append(CityText.getText()); 
    sb.append("\n"); 
    StateIndex = StateList.getSelectedIndex(); 
    sb.append(states[StateIndex]); 
    sb.append("\n"); 
    sb.append(ZipText.getText()); 
    sb.append("\n"); 
    sb.append(PhoneText.getText()); 
    sb.append("\r\n"); 
    fileW.write(sb.toString()); 
    parent.setField(sb.toString()); 
    fileW.close(); 
    MessageTextContractors.setText("A new Contractor has been added!"); 
    ExistTextContractors.setText ("File Contractor.txt exists and can be read from!");
    FileReader fileR = new FileReader("Contractor.txt"); 
    BufferedReader buffIn = new BufferedReader(fileR); 
    String textData = buffIn.readLine(); 
    buffIn.close();

} 
catch (IOException e1) { 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage(), "ERROR", 2); 
} 
NameText.setText(""); 
AddressText.setText(""); 
CityText.setText(""); 
ZipText.setText(""); 
PhoneText.setText(""); 
} 
        catch (IOException e1) { 
        }
    }
}



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){ 
} 
private void Exit_pressed(){ 
System.exit(0); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Can you post your contractdor class?

Comment: I don't see you importing the Contractor class...

Comment: @Erik He is also not importing Customer. So I think it is in the same package?

Comment: Just a couple of thoughts w/o seeing the code - when you copied from Customer to Contractor did you remember to change the name of the class in the file? Can you compile the Contractor class separately to see if it has errors?

Comment: @Erik:  I added the contracor class above.

Comment: this class looks really weird :D

Comment: When pasting a code, please post only the interesting parts of it, not the whole (iow narrow the problem first). It is difficult to read and more unlikely that someone will bother to read that huge amount of code.

Comment: Is it maybe a visibility problem? The class seems to be defined as a private class in another class?

Comment: @Roflcoptr:  Something I notice is if I highlight the word Customer and hold down ctrl-T it brings up the hierarchy which shows Customer - SwinCalc which is right.  But if I do the same with Contractor it says Contractor - SwimCalc.Customer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually this is an import problem. If you're using a good IDE (i.e. Eclipse or Intellij) it will import everything you need if you ask it.)

See [Foo cannot be resolved to a type](http://java.syntaxerrors.info/index.php?title=Foo_cannot_be_resolved_to_a_type/)

Comment: @user381091: I am using Eclipse.  I inserted the imports needed and I get an error that says: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

Comment: There will be something marked in red in your code that is failing compile. You need to fix that. If it's the import that's not compiling then your project classpath is wrong. That is, the files you're trying to import are not on your classpath.

Comment: No errors at import.  The errors are at the word "Contractor" in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted everything in my /target folder and it worked for me.